Search working only on the current page in Angular 17
This search function is searching only from the shown page. If I'm on page1, it searches only on page1; Likewise, if I'm on page2, it searches only on page2.
What changes do I need to do to fix this?
Angular HTML:
<div>
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchQuery" (ngModelChange)="filterPatients()" />
</div>

<div *ngFor="let item of filteredOpdPatients; let count = index">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">{{ count + 1 }}</div>
    <div class="col">{{ item.registration.patientRegistrationId }}</div>
    <div class="col">{{ item.registration.firstName }}</div>
    <div class="col">{{ item.date | date: "dd MMM, yyyy '' hh:mm a" }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
<app-pagination [page]=paginationData.page [collectionSize]=paginationData.total [pageSize]=paginationData.limit  (paginateEvent)="paginateTo($event)"></app-pagination>

Angular TS code:
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { Opd } from 'src/app/interfaces/opd';
import { Pagination } from 'src/app/interfaces/pagination';
import { CoreService } from 'src/app/services/core.service';
import { DashboardService } from '../../dashboard.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-opd-patients',
  templateUrl: './opd-patients.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./opd-patients.component.css']
})
export class OpdPatientsComponent implements OnInit {
  public opdPatients: Opd[] = [];
  public filteredOpdPatients: Opd[] = [];
  public paginationData: Pagination = {} as Pagination;
  public componentQuery = new HttpParams();
  public searchQuery: string = '';

  constructor(
    private coreService: CoreService,
    private router: Router,
    private dashboardService: DashboardService,
    private ngbModal: NgbModal
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getPatients();
  }

  getPatients(): void {
    this.coreService.getOpds(this.componentQuery).subscribe({
      next: (res: any) => {
        this.opdPatients = res.data;
        this.paginationData = res;
        this.filterPatients();
      }
    });
  }

  filterPatients(): void {
    if (!this.searchQuery) {
      this.filteredOpdPatients = [...this.opdPatients];
    } else {
      const query = this.searchQuery.toLowerCase();
      this.filteredOpdPatients = this.opdPatients.filter(patient =>
        patient.registration.patientRegistrationId.toLowerCase().includes(query)
      );
    }
  }

  paginateTo(page: number): void {
    this.componentQuery = this.componentQuery.set('page', page);
    this.getPatients();
  }
}

This is the pagination HTML:
<ngb-pagination (pageChange)="paginateEvent.emit($event)" [collectionSize]="collectionSize" [pageSize]="pageSize" [(page)]="page" aria-label="Custom pagination">
    <ng-template ngbPaginationPrevious>Prev</ng-template>
    <ng-template ngbPaginationNext>Next</ng-template>
</ngb-pagination>

This is the Pagination TS file
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbPaginationConfig, NgbPaginationModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-pagination',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [NgbPaginationModule],
  templateUrl: './pagination.component.html',
  styleUrl: './pagination.component.css'
})
export class PaginationComponent {
@Input() page:number = 1
@Input() pageSize:number = 0
@Input() collectionSize:number = 0
@Output() paginateEvent = new EventEmitter<number>();

constructor(
  ngbPaginationConfig: NgbPaginationConfig
){
  ngbPaginationConfig.size = 'sm';
}
}

Please note that I'm getting 10 items per page from the backend.

problem is in app-pagination could you share that code, if possible a simple stackblitz where the issue happens with some sample data

Added the app-pagination as asked for. Thank you.

The problem seems to be on the server side, you are fetching a particular page of results and then filtering, hence you are getting this behaviour. To fix this, you should first filter the search string on the server and then get the data by pages.
I would suggest you discard the angular side filtering and focus on filtering the data on the API side.
...
export class OpdPatientsComponent implements OnInit {
  public opdPatients: Opd[] = [];
  public filteredOpdPatients: Opd[] = [];
  public paginationData: Pagination = {} as Pagination;
  public componentQuery = new HttpParams();
  public searchQuery: string = '';

  constructor(
    private coreService: CoreService,
    private router: Router,
    private dashboardService: DashboardService,
    private ngbModal: NgbModal
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getPatients();
  }

  getPatients(): void {
    this.componentQuery.set('searchString', this.searchQuery);
    this.coreService.getOpds(this.componentQuery).subscribe({
      next: (res: any) => {
        this.opdPatients = res.data;
        this.paginationData = res;
        this.filterPatients();
      }
    });
  }

  paginateTo(page: number): void {
    this.componentQuery = this.componentQuery.set('page', page);
    this.getPatients();
  }
}

We can also get rid of the filter code both in TS and HTML:
<div>
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchQuery" />
</div>
...


I guess you are right. I'll ask the backend team to look into this and give the necessary APIs. Thank You for your time.
